# Get supervisors uid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to collect all the parents from the top most parent uid.
My user table has the below columns

```
uid,supervisoruid
```

If the given uid is supervisor, I have to collect all the team members of it.
And the team members itself supervisor for some users.

My below picture is my required data(I have to get green Uid's).

[image]

I tried the below query, its not worked for me

```
    SELECT * FROM users u where u.uid in 
   (select distinct uid from users where supervisoruid='100' 
    or uid='100') and u.uid in u.supervisoruid
```

Graph dept is 3 only.

**Sample Data**

[image]

**Input**
100

**Output**
100,101,103

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Some questions: Is the organisation graph always three levels? Given the graph in your example, what would be the input parameter to your query, and what result would you expect?

Comment: Can you give sample data of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join to find children of 100, who have one or more child records of their own.

**Sample Data**

```
-- Sample data taken from OP.
DECLARE @User TABLE
    (
        [UID]               INT PRIMARY KEY,
        supervisorUID       INT
    )
;


INSERT INTO @User
    (
        [UID],
        supervisorUID
    )
VALUES
    (100, 100),
    (101, 100),
    (102, 100),
    (103, 100),
    (104, 100),
    (105, 101),
    (106, 101),
    (107, 101),
    (108, 103),
    (109, 103),
    (110, 103)
;
```

**Query**

```
/* Self join returns any records with a supervisorUID of 100
 * and 1 or more children.
 */
SELECT
    parent.[UID]
FROM
    @User AS parent
        INNER JOIN @User AS child           ON child.supervisorUID = parent.[UID]
WHERE
    parent.supervisorUID = 100
GROUP BY
    parent.[UID]
;
```

Filtering the parent table for a supervisorUID of 100 returns the records 100, 101, 102, 103 and 104.  The self join removes 102 and 104 as they do not appear in the supervisorUID column for any of the records.

This technique would break down if your graph had more than three levels.

Comment: Your answer works as I expected. Thanks for spending your time

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Recursive SQL:

```
-- Sample data taken from OP.
DECLARE @User TABLE
  (
    [UID]               INT PRIMARY KEY,
    supervisorUID       INT
  )
;


INSERT INTO @User
(
    [UID],
    supervisorUID
)
VALUES
(100, 200),
(101, 100),
(102, 100),
(103, 100),
(104, 100),
(105, 101),
(106, 101),
(107, 101),
(108, 103),
(109, 103),
(110, 103)
;
```

Recursive SQL query

```
with Recursivetable (Supervisoruid, uid,  level)
as
(
-- anchor point
select e.supervisoruid, e.uid,
0 as level
from @User as e
where e.supervisoruid = '200'


union all


select e.supervisoruid, e.uid,
LEVEL + 1
from @User as e

inner join Recursivetable as d
on e.supervisorUID = d.uid
)



select distinct Supervisoruid
/* remove distinct and and below comment-- for entire tree */
--, uid,  level
from Recursivetable


go
```